# Chart with .NET from .. scratch: how to approach?

Tags: .net, graphics

i would like to create a simple charting system in .NET considering the portability in Linux and OsX.
How to approach ? 
Is enough to study the System.Drawing component ?

I would like to create chart like "line", "bars", "candlestick" for an home made stock charting software...

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** I would like to create it from scratch because i need the possibility to "design" inside the chart like major technical analisys software on the market. Pre-built charting systems don't allow to design inside the cart

Comment: ASP.NET, Winforms, Silverlight or ?

Comment: You want to create a new charting system that you can port to LINUX ond OS X?  You don't want to use something that's already available like this one: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are somewhat new to .NET so...

I would recommend you use a pre built bar chart control and focus on getting the chart populated with data.

No use in reinventing what Microsoft has already built for you.

Here is a tutorial for ASP.NET :

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2007092201&page=1